# Expectation of product of cosines

Tags: probability, trigonometry

I am reading a paper that starts with
$$
  E[ \cos( a(x-y) ] = E[ \cos(a x) \cos(a y) + \sin(a x) \sin(a y) ] 
$$
where the expectation is over $a$,
then converts it into something of the form
$$
= 2 E[ \cos(a x + c) \cos(a y + c) ] 
$$
where $c$ is chosen randomly from $0,2\pi$
and (I assume) the expectation is over both $(a,c)$,
and perhaps $a$ is different than the $a$ above.

I do not follow how to get to this second form.   Anyone?